# React Native different rendering between iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

So I wanted to try out this map example https://codedaily.io/tutorials/9/Build-a-Map-with-Custom-Animated-Markers-and-Region-Focus-when-Content-is-Scrolled-in-React-Native

where the full code can be found here: https://github.com/browniefed/map_animated_scrollview/blob/master/index.ios.js

It's fairly easy to use and works on iOS like a charm, but not on Android and looks like this (to the left iPhone X, to the right Pixel 2 XL):

[image: Circels aren't rendered.]

Obviously, the circles around the marker on the map aren't rendered on android. I know that in some cases you need different code bases for each operating system, but I can't find a solution in this case.

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "overflow: hidden" style property of the "ring" style component does not work on android at this point as mentioned over here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3198

Also in this thread are some kind of solutions and workarounds, but neither did work for me. I abandoned the circles at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the styling is right? Maybe the code is right but it is being displayed somewhere outside the screen. I always had problems with it. It looks awesome on ios but android doesn't and vice versa. Look at the position : "absolute" maybe it causes it to disappear.

Comment: did not change anything. Just destroys the layout on the iPhone too.  I think the error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: I read the guide again and in the last paragraph it states: "This will only work on iOS, the ring styling and such would need to be modified since Android doesn't support overflow: visible yet." Didn't read it ... my bad. I am now trying to find a solution for this.